# How can I set an user with none affiliation directly to be a member when the user joins the room - Ejabberd

Tags: erlang, mongoose, xmpp, ejabberd, erlang-otp

I am customising the module mod_muc_room to automatically set the affiliation of an user to  member when the user joins for the first time.

I am working on the method process_pressence, i manage to add the user in the configuration room of the mysql table mod_muc  but the StateData does not contain this change.... how can I properly make this change available to the StateData.

I would like to know some pointers. I have tried many many method hacks but I just seem to get lost...thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/guide_en.html#modmuc

How about setting `members_by_default` to true in `default_room_options` ?

---

edit:

I was confused about role and affiliation, and try following patch:

```
--- a/src/mod_muc_room.erl
+++ b/src/mod_muc_room.erl
@@ -1611,7 +1611,11 @@ add_online_user(JID, Nick, Role, StateData) ->
                           end,
                           [LJID], StateData#state.nicks),
     tab_add_online_user(JID, StateData),
-    StateData#state{users = Users, nicks = Nicks}.
+    StateData1 = case get_affiliation(JID, StateData) of
+        owner -> StateData;
+        _ -> set_affiliation(JID, member, StateData)
+    end,
+    StateData1#state{users = Users, nicks = Nicks}.
```

Comment: {moderated, true}, {members_by_default, true},
 {members_only, false}, {allow_user_invites, false},
 {password_protected, false}, {captcha_protected, false},
 {password, []}, {anonymous, true}, {logging, false},
 {max_users, 200}, {allow_voice_requests, true},
 {voice_request_min_interval, 1800},
 {captcha_whitelist, []},
 {affiliations,
  [{{"gallero", "dev.here.com", []}, {owner, []}}]},
 {subject, []}, {subject_author, []}] | 2014-01-31 14:57:25  ---------------  Muc options look like these but I need  participants to have member affiliation directly, without the need to the owner to add

Comment: If you can customize `mod_muc_room.erl`, find the way to make `Affiliation` become `member` in `add_new_user()`. You can find elegant way, or just do `Affiliation = member`. I just read the code and suggest this, not tested it.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused about role and affiliation. I will edit my first answer.

Comment: I was doing the almost the same case but in a separate method just in the very end after processing the new presence, but this seems to work!